# Fixing compilation error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I am very very new to VC++ and not so comfortable in C++ too. I am trying get a project running but unable to fix these errors: `error C3861: 'fmod': identifier not found`
This project was running pretty fine but some problem with configuration causing this. Any idea why this could be? Very sorry for a very basic question!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem with cmath.

Try to include cmath

```
#include <cmath>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell you much about this, without you give some more context (the code where this error appears).

Most probably you've been missing to

```
 #include <cmath>
```

or to apply `std::` namespace for [`std::fmod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/), you could also do (apart from what Aleksandar said):

```
#include <ctgmath>
```

See also: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctgmath/